# nodejs wait for exec in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, exec

I like to integrate exec from nodejs in a custom function to handle all the errors in this one function.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function os_func() {
    this.execCommand = function(cmd) {
        var ret;
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }
            ret = stdout;
        });
        return ret;
    }
}
var os = new os_func();
```

This function returns undefined because exec isn't finished when the value returns.
How can i solve that? Can i force the function to wait for exec?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the command is executed asynchronously you will want to use a [callback](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) to handle the return value once the command has finished executing:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function os_func() {
    this.execCommand = function(cmd, callback) {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            callback(stdout);
        });
    }
}
var os = new os_func();

os.execCommand('SomeCommand', function (returnvalue) {
    // Here you can get the return value
});
```

Answer (score 21):

Yet another solution using ES6 modules:

```js
import fs from "node:fs";
import {exec} from "node:child_process";
import util from "node:util";

// promisify exec
const execPromise = util.promisify(exec);

try {
  // wait for exec to complete
  const {stdout, stderr} = await execPromise("ls -l");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

you can use promise as :

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function os_func() {
    this.execCommand = function (cmd) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
           exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
             if (error) {
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            resolve(stdout)
           });
       })
   }
}
var os = new os_func();

os.execCommand('pwd').then(res=> {
    console.log("os >>>", res);
}).catch(err=> {
    console.log("os >>>", err);
})
```

Answer (score 6):

*exec* will deal with it in an async fashion, so you should receive a callback or return a promise.

One thing you could do in order to make it sync is to use *execSync* instead:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

> The child_process.execSync() method is generally identical to
>   child_process.exec() with the exception that the method will not
>   return until the child process has fully closed. When a timeout has
>   been encountered and killSignal is sent, the method won't return until
>   the process has completely exited. Note that if the child process
>   intercepts and handles the SIGTERM signal and doesn't exit, the parent
>   process will wait until the child process has exited.

Answer (score 5):

Adding what worked for me, as none of the above did the trick!

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const util  = require("util");
const execPromise = util.promisify(exec);

function parentFunction() {
...
  // Trigger 'exec', then a-wait for it to finish
  await execWrapper('<your-command-here>');
...
}

...
async function execWrapper(cmd) {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await execPromise(cmd);
  if (stdout) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stdout}`);
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }
}
```

NOTE: This isn't your example, but just a generic one; for me - the `cmd` was a Docker `build` command. You could probably have `execWrapper` return back the `stdout` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with callback. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
function os_func() {
this.execCommand = function(cmd, myCallback) {
    var ret;
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
        }
        ret = stdout;
        myCallback(ret);

    });
}


function myCallback(ret){
      // TODO: your stuff with return value...
}
```