# Force Javascript (node) to wait on exec

Tags: javascript, exec

I want to make my main process wait on some output from an exec.

I want to force the program to perform the steps in sequence, waiting for each step before going onto the next step. I feel this should be easy, yet I cannot see how to do it.

With other languages it is the default to wait on things, in Perl for example the following 5 lines would do exactly what I want.

```
print("START")
print(`sleep 3; echo 1`)
print(`sleep 2; echo 2`)
print(`sleep 1; echo 3`)
print("END")
```

How to do it in Node JavaScript?

Here is my code so far

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function sleepy1() {
  exec("sleep 3; echo 1", function( stderr, stdout ) {
    console.log( stdout.trim() )
  })
}

function sleepy2() {
  exec("sleep 2; echo 2", function( stderr, stdout ) {
    console.log( stdout.trim() )
  })
}

function sleepy3() {
  exec("sleep 1; echo 3", function( stderr, stdout ) {
    console.log( stdout.trim() )
  })
}

console.log("START")
sleepy1()
sleepy2()
sleepy3()
console.log("END")
```

Here is the output from the code:

```
$ node make_it_wait.js 
START
END
3
2
1
```

Comment: This is a [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037042/nodejs-wait-for-exec-in-function), please search StackOverflow before asking a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can promisify `exec` and await until each command finishes:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const execa = util.promisify(exec);

function sleepy1() {
  return execa("sleep 3; echo 1")
}

function sleepy2() {
  return execa("sleep 2; echo 2")
}

function sleepy3() {
  return execa("sleep 1; echo 3")
}

async function main() {
    console.log((await sleepy1()).stdout)
    console.log((await sleepy2()).stdout)
    console.log((await sleepy3()).stdout)
}


console.log("START");
main().then(() => console.log("END"))
```

As pointed out in another answer, there's also the sync variant of exec, `execSync`. If what you do is a script or another one-pass program, you might find that easier to use. In a server/multiprocess environment it's better to use async/await.